# Can modern GPU runs multiple kernels simultaneously?

Tags: gpu

As far as I know,

GPU can simultaneously run thousands of threads that belong to one GPU kernel process, and that is the reason why it called SIMT.

However, can GPGPU simultaneously run multiple threads that belong to different GPU kernel processes? If possible, does it mean that those threads can run on one of GPU cores, and multiple cores can run simultaneously? Or does it mean that even one GPU core can run multiple threads belongs to different kernels?

Or simply, is it only possible to run threads that belong to the same GPU kernel process at a time on the entire GPU cores?

Comment: Do you mean, for example, one GPU being used by multiple virtual machines on the same computer?

Comment: I think it doesn't need to be restricted to virtual machine environment. I mean, if multiple GPU kernels exist at one time, can different GPU kernels run on different GPU cores at the same time? or only one GPU kernel can take advantage of all GPU cores?